# HAProxy SSL Responses Very Slow

Tags: haproxy, openssl

Even though CPU usage is low, and http responses are very quick, SSL responses are taking longer than 10+ seconds to respond.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the OpenSSL library needs to have the hostname properly set in `/etc/hosts`, if not it will block on lookups. Discovered this behavior by running strace on one of the ssl procs.

`127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
close(519) = 0 
stat("/etc/krb5.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=685, ...}) = 0 
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 299 
fstat(299, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=209, ...}) = 0`

Comment: What does "properly set" mean here?