# Simple haproxy TCP passthrough results in very slow network transfer speed

Tags: networking, performance, haproxy, passthrough

I've setup a simple haproxy instance on a clean install of Debian 10 Buster. I've added some simple necessary config to enable the passthrough to the IP address in question (which has been redacted in the below config).

The config file:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice

    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
    #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http


frontend myfrontend
  bind *:80
  mode tcp
  default_backend mybackendhttp

frontend myfrontendhttps
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  use_backend mybackendhttps

backend mybackendhttp
  mode tcp
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server1 ***********:80

backend mybackendhttps
  mode tcp
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server1 ************:443
```

The changes I did (if I do a diff with the original file) (redacted ip):

```
+
+
+frontend myfrontend
+  bind *:80
+  mode tcp
+  default_backend mybackendhttp
+
+frontend myfrontendhttps
+  bind *:443
+  mode tcp
+  use_backend mybackendhttps
+
+backend mybackendhttp
+  mode tcp
+  option ssl-hello-chk
+  server server1 ***********:80
+
+backend mybackendhttps
+  mode tcp
+  option ssl-hello-chk
+  server server1 **********:443
```

Everything works correctly, but for some reason the network performance is incredibly slow when doing a browser request from my PC, curl request via command line or mobile, I'm getting about 200-300kb/s when usually I'd be getting around 10x that.

If I try the same request via curl on a VPS I get a much higher speed (5000kb/s).

The haproxy is running on a GCP compute instance VM so I doubt it'd be a network bandwidth issue, but I can try setup a simple static http service and see how that compares.

What might be the cause of the issue? How could I diagnose this? Would enabling logs on haproxy provide better insight into this issue?

I have come across the following question which also seems to describe similar behavior:

[HAProxy SSL Responses Very Slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/604075/haproxy-ssl-responses-very-slow)

> the OpenSSL library needs to have the hostname properly set in /etc/hosts

However it's not clear to me what "properly set" means.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I don't have enough rep.

In `/etc/hosts`, you want to find this line:

`127.0.0.1  localhost`

Replace `localhost` with your FQDN, like haproxy.domain.com or whatever it is. It should be the same as your server's hostname.

On Debian, you can set the hostname with this command:

`hostname-ctl set-hostname haproxy.domain.com`